# help me to cheat with numericUpDown1_ValueChanged event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Form and numericupdown control located on it. I want that in some conditions (_condition1) user cannot be able to change a value of numericupdown control. How can I do it ? I wrote some code but **it works twice (double time).**

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    bool _condition1;

    int _previousValue;

    void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           if(_condition1)
           {
                 numericUpDown1.Value = (decimal)_previousValue;
           }
           else
           {
                 _previousValue = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
           }
    }
}
```

Control must be enable.

Comment: It fires twice because you set the Value yourself, thus triggering the event again.

Comment: klausbyskov, I know it. How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numericUpDown1.ReadOnly = true;

?

.... edit: ..........

Another (ugly) solution would be to remove the event, change the value, and add the event again ..

```
numericupdown1.ValueChanged -= new EventHandler ....
numericupdown1.Value = value;
numericupdown1.ValueChanged += new EventHandler ....
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't fit me. It blocks an user input and makes a grey backgorund color...

Comment: The reason it fires twice, is because when the event gets fired, and condition 1 is true, you change the value yourself, which fires the 'ValueChanged' event again. ..

Comment: Also, you could set readonly true, and BackColor white ... gives the same look

Comment: Thanks! I will use the solution with += and -=

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Validating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx) event?

**EDIT #1** Have you tried the [Leave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave.aspx?PHPSESSID=6c7e47uec18v8n3121a6p001h4) event?